# Is it possible to use Kendo's React Toolbar with other React components?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

We have been upgrading our front end which already uses Kendo UI for jQuery with their newly released React components.

One of our existing components is a Toolbar which houses some buttons and drop down menus, but so far it appears that you can only use the React Toolbars own configuration object to render anything inside the toolbar. Which is limiting to use.

Is it possible to use other Kendo UI React Components or even your own React Components inside the Kendo UI React Toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbar is React wrapper of the jQuery kendo UI Toolbar. Thus it is not possible to add react components inside it.
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/wrappers/buttons/toolbar/

The suite is now extended to have Components written entirely on React and they can be nested one another.
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/buttons/

The pure implementations does not have toolbar, but it have the ButtonGroup, the rest of the toolbar is just styling, and since it works with the same theme, you can achieve it by setting some classNames.

```
             <div className="k-toolbar k-widget k-toolbar-resizable"> 
               <ButtonGroup width="300px">
                   <Button togglable={true} icon="bold">Bold</Button>
                   <Button togglable={true} icon="italic">Italic</Button>
                   <Button togglable={true} icon="underline">Underline</Button>
               </ButtonGroup >
               <div data-overflow="auto" className="k-separator">&nbsp;</div>
               <Button icon="bold">Bold</Button>
             </div>
```